# Bootstrap dropdown menu cannot float left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this nav that has a dropdown

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SearchICE</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
         <div class="input-group len">
          <input type="text" class="form-control sblength" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-success bround" type="button">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="btn-group ml-auto">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Account
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div
      </nav>
```

and this is the dropdown

```
<div class="btn-group ml-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Account
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yztumo0x/1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/yztumo0x/1/show

The `account` dropdown do not float left and instead protrudes to the right where its not visiable.

How can i fix this?

Comment: on which side of the dropdown, how do you want it to look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working fine for me. Check the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/ZEQeQLR). Make sure you have imported the right js and css files.

```
<div class="btn-group ml-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Account
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No its not. In your codepen example, its still going too much to the right. I would like it to face left when dropping down.

Comment: Ahh i see, i think i misunderstood. Change the `dropdown-menu-left` => `dropdown-menu-right`. Check the edits above.

Comment: I cant get it to work https://github.com/britisharmy/search That's the repo

Comment: Check out this repo: https://github.com/paarth1995/Bootstrap-Repo. So i am not very familiar with setting up the project the way you have done, you can fork this repo and see how i have set up the project with all the imports. The dropdown is working fine in this.

Comment: You may need to setup the html and styles the way you want but the emphasis for mostly on the structure and imports. Hope it helps.

Comment: many thanks. I see that it works. Let me see what the problem was.